# My Prim's Algorithm (MST) runs much faster in a matrix than in a list

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have some trouble implementing Prim's algorithm for finding Minimum Spanning Tree in a graph. 
1. I generate an adjacency matrix, and run the algorithm to work on this matrix. The code:

```
void Graph::Prim(){
    int i=,j;
    int x=0,y=0,min,count=0;
    bool* visited=new bool[this->vertices_number]; // array of visited vertices

    for (int a=0;a<this->vertices_number;a++)
        visited[a]=false;

    visited[0]=true; // checking the first vertex (start looking here)

    while(count < this->vertices_number-1){
    min=INFINITY; //defined in header (large int)
        for (int i=0;i<this->vertices_number;i++){              
            if (visited[i]==true){                              // looking for minimum-weight edge in all visited vertices
                for(j=0;j<this->vertices_number;j++){           //looking in one column
                    if (this->AdjacencyMatrix[i][j]<min && this->AdjacencyMatrix[i][j]>0 && visited[j]==false){ 
                    /* looking for lowest-weight edge which isn't already connected to the tree and isn't 0*/
                        min=AdjacencyMatrix[i][j]; //value
                        x=i;                        //row
                        y=j;                        //column
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        visited[y]=true; //  added vertex
    //  cout << x << "-->" << y << " : (" << min << ")"<<endl;
        count++; // visited vertex
    }
}
```

Then, I want to do the same, but using an array of lists containing links.

```
class Link
{
public:
int destination;
int weight;
...
};
```

So I create an adjacency list:

```
list<Link> *AdjacencyList;
AdjacencyList=new list<Link>[vertices_number];
```

So in the end the whole list is filled, ex. if vertex 0 and 4 are connected and the weight of connection is 7, AdjacencyList[0] contains Link with destination=4 and weight=7.

I modified only the main loop of the algorithm, so now it uses iterator to find what it needs:

```
    if (visited[i]==true){ 
        for(list<Link>::iterator it = AdjacencyList[i].begin(); it != AdjacencyList[i].end(); it++){
            if ( visited[it->destination]==false && it->weight < min){
                x=i;
                y=it->destination;
                min=it->weight;
```

The algorithms are able to find the same MST with no problems, the only thing is, the one which works on matrix is much faster, which is very surprising to me. For example, in a 80000 edges graph (random), while using matrix, the tree is found in miliseconds, but using list: whole second. Can anybody help me with this, or give a hint how to make this code more effective?

Comment: Have you tried it with `vector`?

Comment: Tried allocating the memory beforehand for a list? vector has a reserve function. May be list has something like that?

Comment: @Prabhu: no `reserve` for `list` (it does not make sense), however there is a `resize` if you are willing to have dummy elements.

Comment: I tried vector, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly believe that the implementation using the array is faster than the implementation using lists because it provides better memory locality, i.e. it is more friendly to the cache.

Comment: Extremely probable indeed, given that `list` is a very specialized container that trades off memory efficiency for stability whereas `vector` and `deque` are much more memory efficient (at the cost of stability in a number of cases).

Comment: Interesting, I thought that, while using matrix, at some point I will have to go through every index, which will cause n^2 complexity.

Comment: related benchmarks, in case you want to update your answer with data: [std::vector VS std::list VS std::deque](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html)

Comment: I tried vector instead of list, but it still takes a long time to complete the algorithm. How can I make this program run in O(E logV) complexity? The complexity while using matrix is indeed O(n^2), I just checked it, and complexity while using list is n^2, too, but the time is increasing much faster.
According to this:
http://www.comp.dit.ie/rlawlor/alg_ds/mst/prim.pdf
I should get O( E logV).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is is because you are doing very dense memory accesses, hence the dense representation wins out. That is, you are looping over your entire Adjacency matrix, in row major order, meaning you are taking full advantage of caching. In the case of the linked list, each new element added is allocated new memory on the heap that may not be contiguous.

For Prim's you should use some form of priority queue.

Comment: OK, so I should have a priority queue of edges coming out of each vertex, both in matrix and list representation? Then I won't be looping over the data container, looking for the smallest (not yet linked) edge, but I will have it saved in that queue?

Comment: Yea, the whole purpose of a priority queue is to keep track of items by some notion of priority. In this case, you want to track the potential edges you can add weighted by their edge weight. This then means you don't have to loop over all tentative edges to be added everytime.